Correction for clips, bolts, and ties
I was given a Michigan inspection "notice of correction" tag, stating:

Hurricane clips/screws needed on rafters
Carrier needs to be through bolted to post
Need rafter ties/collar ties

I am looking for the correct code, exceptions, and verbiage for an attempt to provide an argument to the local building department for a review against #1 & #3. I assume #2 is probably legit.
I built a garage pole-barn style, with the help from my father. He is retired but has over 30 years in residential framing. He owns a code book from 2005 which doesn't have references to hurricane clips. I also looked in the two online code books for these requirements without success. Being the Building codes and Residential codes both from 2015 and effective.
The last time I was working professional in framing, about 2017, I definitely installed these metal strips. I remember they were meant to be applied on the inside of the wall from the top plates to the rafter.
That said I will emphasize I did not use walls but posts with purlins, and put a 2x10 as an outside wall header that the rafters are sitting on. Then I also have an inside header and a 2x6 block nailed between both headers then to the rafter. This, in my opinion, provides far superior protection against wall expansion and load (or uplift) forces. 
I was also under the belief that as I am using a beam in the center (the rafters are resting on top of the headers) and not butted to a ridge board (which in the scenario of a ridge board separation can occur), that collar ties are not necessary. As with the outer walls, I also used blocking for connecting the rafters to the headers/beam. 
I regards to the correction #2, I am assuming his use of the word carrier, is my headers being used as beams to carrier the rafters. The center beams span 17 feet, the back wall spans 8 feet between posts, the front has posts 4 feet from corners and then 9 feet in for garage doors. I have 5 screw/nails in each header at each post. The center beams I also put an extra metal carrying flange, with 4 additional screws. I am not sure if this bolt requirement is for all posts or just those in the center. Thoughts?

You should be talking directly to the inspector to get their interpretation of the requirements.
